# set_locales en_US fails

Tags: php

i'm trying to set locales to en_US, but it returns nothing?!

```
setLocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');
```

is it the right code i'm using?

Comment: Getting the right locale can be a nightmare. See the user contributed notes to setlocale() for help: http://www.php.net/setlocale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `en_US` locale may not be installed on your system, or your system doesn't support locales at all. See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php):

> Returns the new current locale, or FALSE if the locale functionality is not implemented on your platform, the specified locale does not exist or the category name is invalid.